# How to easily toggle outlines and fills for polygon layers (in QGIS 3.x)?

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

So I want to be able to easily toggle outlines and fills for polygon layers in the Layers List.
I managed to make two rules (both with the rule 'true') and then they will show up in the Layers List:

[image: rule-based-symbol-rendering-options]

But... I want to make sure that all of the symbol options stay in the legend after unchecking them. What happens now is that when I uncheck the fill, it disappears from the layers list, and then I need to double click to go back into the symbology settings and check it from there. But... that kinda defeats the point of having a convenient way to toggle the outlines and fill styles independently.

Are there any easy solutions for this that I couldn't find in the settings? Or shall I open a feature request?

Comment: You could duplicate the layer and style them accordingly, or you could use classified symbologies?

Comment: @Erik, i did try layer duplicate, but I find it to be a cleaner solution to have a single layer with multiple style rules. The rule based seems to work fine to get the check boxes to show up and to program different styles for the different rules. What do you mean by classified? categorized? or? Would that provide an advantage over "rule-based" ?

Comment: Classified, categorized, same-same =P

Comment: If your goal is to have different symbol styles fast selectable you can use also the Style Manager panel creating different style to recall just with one click. If your goal is to have all the option visible in the Layer Panel I think that JGH answers solve your problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure the `filter legend by map content` is deactivated

[image]

Comment: I am accepting this answer, and still curious if there are other workflow options to achieve this. I acknowledge that @Erik 's proposal to duplicate the layer and change that style can work, but it i prefer not to have multiple layers pointing at the same data source if at all possible (just feels cleaner).